# Hot water heater volume

Tags: leak, water-heater

I have a leak either in my sprinkler system or in the house pipes. How can I tell if the water is draining from my hot water heater?

Comment: You suspect that your water heating is leaking? How do you even know that you have a leak?

Comment: I have a leak. I unsure if it's the sprinkler system or house pipes. I dug a hole to try to locate the leak. The ground around the hole is supersaturated. The hole continues to fill even after I shut off the water at the water main. It could be simply water draining from the ground. I don't hear any water running/dripping in the house. Should I be concerned that my water heater could drain & damage the water heater.

Comment: As long as you haven't opened the drain at the bottom of the tank, your hot water tank requires water pressure from the cold line to push the hot water out of it. Without pressure from the cold water circuit, the water in the tank will just sit there. No risk of damage.

Comment: I am not sure why you are tying the sprinkler system with the hot water heater.

Comment: Is the water heater gas or electric? Doesn't your sprinkler system have a shutoff valve where it connects to your water line from the meter? These are usually in a box in the yard not too far from the water meter.

Comment: Where is this property, what state? Where in the house is the water heater located--basement, garage, closet in living space, attic . . . ?

Comment: Is this a slab fundation, a pier and beam, or a full basement?